# Append img without default "next line" padding

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, dom

I've reviewed related questions (and answers), so I'm trying to keep a duplicate off the site.

Here's the issue; I'm doing a little image slider that uses php to first take all images inside a directory, and spits out 7 of them:

```
<div id="imageScroller">
<div id="wide">
<?php
    $images = scandir("folder/folder/folder");
    for($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++){
        echo "<img src='folder/folder/folder/" . $images[$i] . "' name='" . $i . "' class='imgScroll'>";
    }
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Then it passes the `$images` array and the counter `$i` to Javascript:

```
var images = new Array();
images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
var i = <?php echo json_encode($i); ?>;
```

`setInterval` for the repeating function and animates the images to the left, appending a new image and removing the first image with each pass:

```
setInterval("newImg()", 3000);
function newImg(){
    if(i == images.length){
        i = 2; //The PHP array returns the first two folders as [0] => ., [1] => ..
    }
    $("#wide").children().first().animate({'marginLeft': '-93px'}, 3000, function(){
    $("#wide").append("<img src='folder/folder/folder/" + images[i] + "' name='" + i + "' class='imgScroll'>\n").children().first().remove();
    i++;
    });
}
```

And some CSS to wrap up the excerpts:

```
        #imageScroller{
            width: 100%;
            height: 114px;
            width: 651px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #wide{
            width: 837px;
        }
        .imgScroll{
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            height: 114px;
            width: 83px;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
```

So my issue is that since I'm creating `img` elements at different times, **how do I get rid of the spacing inbetween images that are on different lines?** Or, simply, append the images so that according to the browser they're all on the same line?

Comment: padding top and bottom set at 0 ?

Comment: The padding to the left and right is the one that is messig up.

Comment: I think you want display: inline;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set line-height and font-size to 0:

```
#wide {
    width: 837px;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

This is the simplest hack when you deal with inline elements.

Comment: Worked like a charm. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try going:

```
.imgScroll { display: inline-block; }
```